# Unity button desabling not working on Android device(database problem I think)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity for the first time.

I am making a app to work on Android platform.

I made a script to add to one button. The interface has a text input field to add names of a group. After writing some name and hit one button (adicionar), it should add the name in a text field (named textoGrupo). It would also enabled a second button (named seguinte), that would be disabled since the begining of the script execution. I also have another text field (textoElementoRepetido) that should have text only if the name written is repeated.

It works fine when I tested it in Unity. But when I test it on my Android device it does nothing of what's on the script.

Here is my code:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.SqliteClient;
using TMPro;
using System.IO;

public class grupo : MonoBehaviour
{
List<string> elementos = new List<string>();
private IDbConnection connection;
private IDbCommand command;
string dbFile;

int idGrupo = 0;
public TMP_InputField input;
public TMP_Text textoGrupo;
public TMP_Text textoElementoRepetido;
public Button seguinte;


// Start is called before the first frame update
IEnumerator Start()
{

    // Ligação à base de dados
    string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/TVdatabase.db";

    if (!File.Exists(filepath))

    {
        // if it doesn't ->
        // open StreamingAssets directory and load the db ->
        WWW loadDB = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/TVdatabase.db");  // this is the path to your StreamingAssets in android

        while (!loadDB.isDone)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(30);
        }  // CAREFUL here, for safety reasons you shouldn't let this while loop unattended, place a timer and error check

        // then save to Application.persistentDataPath

        File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, loadDB.bytes);

    }

    //open db connection

    connection = new SqliteConnection("URI=file:" + filepath);

    seguinte.interactable = false;

}

public void AdicionaElemento( )
{
    if (input.text != null && input.text != "")
    {
        string sql;

        //se ainda não existirem elementos no grupo, é criado na base de dados um grupo e o seu id é guardado

        if (elementos.Count == 0)
        {
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            connection.Open();

            sql = "INSERT INTO Grupo(idAvatar) VALUES(1);";
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sql = "SELECT MAX(idGrupo) FROM GRUPO;";
            command.CommandText = sql;
            IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                idGrupo = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        string elemento = input.text.ToString();

        if (!elementos.Contains(item: elemento))
        {
            textoElementoRepetido.text = "";

            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            connection.Open();

            sql = "INSERT INTO Elemento(nomeElemento, idGrupo) VALUES('" + elemento + "', " + idGrupo + ");";

            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

            if (elementos.Count == 0)
            {
                textoGrupo.text += elemento;
            }
            else
            {
                textoGrupo.text += ", " + elemento;
            }
            elementos.Add(elemento);
            seguinte.interactable = true;
            input.text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            textoElementoRepetido.text = "Essa pessoa já faz parte do teu grupo!";
        }
    }
     else{
         seguinte.interactable = false;
     }
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
```

}

I hope I wrote enough to understand the purpose of this screen. Here is what I attached to the button adicionar.

[image: attached on button]

If first tried it on the onClick() event. Didn't work. So I tried it on a trigger. Same result.

I have no idea why this works on unity editor but not on my  Android device.

When I click the button adicionar with nothing on text input field the script is working. So my guess is the real problem is teh connection with the database.

I missed some steps when making the database connection. I was following [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-3d-android-sqlite-examples.114660/). But it still does not work.

My database file is named TVbatabase.db

Comment: I think some debugging and breakpoints could help..

Comment: I don't quite understand the line `WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!assets/" + "TVdatabase.db");` are you trying to copy the DB file from `Application.dataPath` to `Applocation.persistentDataPath`? What is `jar:file://` for? I guess you are getting an `www` error but not checking for it ... you shouldn't simply assume you are getting your DB content without any checks

Comment: After I read you update, yes, it could be from another problem and causing Unity behave strangely. It's best if you debug the device using adb by plugging your device and run this command  `adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG`

Comment: @derHugo I just updated my code. It's the first time I'm working with unity, android and SQLite. But I did the steps on this [link]https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-3d-android-sqlite-examples.114660/ .

Comment: It looks like you are looking for [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html)

Comment: So @derHugo, you're saying that instead of `WWW loadDB = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/TVdatabase.db")` I should have `WWW loadDB = new WWW(Application.streamingAssetsPath+ "/TVdatabase.db")`? 
I already tried it and the button seguinte starts disabled, but the rest of the script does not work.

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for spending some time with my question. I already find out what was wrong, it's in the answer bellow.

Comment: I'm glad you could figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. So I followed the same link that is in my question ([this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-3d-android-sqlite-examples.114660/)). I had error, didn't know why. So I downloaded the package in that post. I realised that I did not have all the necessary plugins. I did not know they where necessary. After I imported them it worked.